# best way to return all keys more than X es6

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, object, ecmascript-6

I have an objects with keys sorted asc.

```
{
0: {},
4: {},
85: {},
266: {},
}
```

i want to get all the keys where keys > X(=50).

in this case it will return

```
{

    85: {},
    266: {},
}
```

I want it to be performant because im doing this every 500ms with more than 100+ keys

Comment: did you know the max possible value of key?

Comment: 86400 @KoushikChatterjee ...

Comment: and is your value of `X` getting changed?

Comment: yeah every 500ms

Comment: processing ~100 keys twice a second is no significant load. Processing 1000+ items every frame *(~16-20ms)* would be a load where you could *start* thinking about performance. Or processing 10000+ items at a time. Something like that. Don't optimize before you actually have a performance problem.

Comment: if you know that your keys are not going to change, then you ca check my answer, it will be little faster, specially when you have more keys like 1000+ or 10,000+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are running this very frequently, and if we are assuming that the values are only changing no new keys are introducing/deleting, then we can look for those keys mached the criteria, the moment it dose not matches we will break execution, here we go:

```
var obj = {
  0: {},
  4: {},
  85: {},
  266: {},
};
var keys = Object.keys(obj).sort((a,b)=>a>b); //basically we are caching the keys
```

and in each interval

```
var res = {};
var x = 50; // whatever it is
var idx;
for(idx=keys.length-1;idx>=0;idx--) {
    var key = keys[idx];
    if(key>x) {
        res[key] = obj[key];
    } else {break;} //and here is the magic
}
```

Comment: in the link you provoded, it will be `let keys = Object.keys(obj).sort();` and not `obj = Object.keys(obj).sort();` in preparation code. and then later use keys in execution

Comment: `.sort()` without comparing function sorts the values as Strings, so that `"100" < "5"`.

Comment: so we also can sort desc, and loop forward (kinda same with what we are doing)

Comment: @SlimShady Sorting the object initially seems pointless for me. I would still suggest you to use `for..in` loop to handle big objects. Just check the perf test to make yourself sure about it. https://jsperf.com/forinvsfilter2/1

Comment: @SlimShady And by the way - in your test link you have sorted the object for every test case, but `filter` and `for..in` methods doesn't require that.

Comment: @Kinduser ikr because the test is filling random keys. but in my question the keys are sorted by default therefore its not needed.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest and es6:

```
let obj = ...;

let keys = Object.keys(obj).filter(i => (parseInt(i) || 0) >= 50);
```

Comment: `filter` is avg 50% slower than `for...in`. https://jsperf.com/forinvsfilter    Easiest != fastest.

Comment: @Kinduser That is incorrect. You do not safe check the key by parsing it to an integer. Without the parsing, filter seems to be faster. [Filter beats your for...in everytime](https://jsperf.com/filtervsforin).

Comment: Yeah, your solution works nice, but for **small objects with just few keys**. If we are handling a big ones (like OP does), `for...in` has a better performance. https://jsperf.com/forinvsfilter2/1

Comment: @Kinduser Apparently it is **very slow** indeed for Chrome with a large number of objects. In FireFox filter is faster, with 61%.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `for..in` loop.

Speed test: https://jsperf.com/forinvsfilter

```js
const obj = {
  0: {},
  4: {},
  85: {},
  266: {},
};

let res = {};

for (let r in obj) {
  if (r > 50) {
    res[r] = obj[r];
  }
}

console.log(res);
```